# Unable To Access SSAS via MSMDPump File and URL

Tags: windows, sql, analysis, olap

I had [this same issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/de9f9d4b-a124-4b19-9b9b-b8ea116bf1bd/not-able-to-access-sql-server-analysis-services-on-configured-on-iis?forum=sqlanalysisservices) when trying to connect to SSAS via a MSMDPump file, [as stated in this article.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=asallproducts-allversions&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver15)

> String reference not set to an instance of a String. Parameter name: s
> (mscorlib)

I got the following error message when trying to connect to my MSMDPump.dll via SSMS:

[image]

This when I tried to connect via excel:

[image]

When I examined the Event Log on this server I would see "Audit Failures":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears I got my usernames confused, the "David.Rogers" user didn't exist, instead my user name should've been "DavidRogers", a very confusing set of error message to determine that the user account "David.Rogers" didn't exist.